# How to Call 3rd Party API that uses a Token OAuth To Allow Calls Through Web API Using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2

I am looking to start working on migrating a project I have from a mess of classes to DI pattern where I can inject the object and make my project testable.

I need to call third party api's to handle some their authentication (I consume multiple 3rd party APIs) and one of the things I do is handle a bearer token (OAuth) and I would like to know how or what is the best way to handle an OAuth token or bearer token that has an expiration date.

Originally I used a class with static members and static functions to store the token (24 hour expiration) and if it's not expired no need to go get it just use the bearer token in the variable.

What is the best way or what is a way to adhere this type of token request and response via DI?  I want to do this all server side, this will be a web api that angular or jquery will interact with.  .NET framework standard.

I'd like to add currently I am using Unity for DI.

Comment: I think your question could use a better title.  Right now its just a bunch of tags and isn't very descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use a class to manage that which is registered via DI as a singleton?  Would then in effect be the same as your old Static stuff.

(I'm assuming this is for communication between your server and other servers and isn't directly involving YOUR api clients)

If you don't like the idea of having some sort of big bloated singleton floating about all the time, you could simply abstract just the *storage* of the token away using something like this:

```
public interface ITokenStore
{
    string GetCurrentToken();
    void SetToken(string token);
}

public class TokenStore : ITokenStore
{
    private DateTime _tokenRefreshedAt;
    private string _currentToken;
    public string GetCurrentToken()
    {
        //if we last got the token more than 23 hours ago,
        //just reset token
        if (lastTokenRefreshed.AddHours(23) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            _currentToken = null;
        }
        return _currentToken;        
    }
    public void SetCurrentToken(string token)
    {
        _currentToken = token;
    }
}
```

and then register this as a singleton (not familiar with Unity, so adjust syntax to suit):

```
container.RegisterSingleton<ITokenStore, TokenStore>();
```

then your service(s) which need the token can be registered with per-request or transient lifetimes, and just do stuff like:

```
class SomeService
{
    private ITokenStore _tokenStore;

    public SomeService(ITokenStore tokenStore)
    {
        _tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }

    public string DoThings(params..)
    {
        var currentToken = _tokenStore.GetCurrentToken();
        if (currentToken == null)
        {
           currentToken = GetNewTokenSomehow();
           _tokenStore.SetCurrentToken(currentToken);          
        }

       .... Do other things....
    }

}
```

you could make the tokenstore class itself do the fetching of a new token, but if its lifetime is singleton then so would any services you inject into it have to be, so I'd probably have a per-request-lifetime TokenManager which deals with all that but itself uses the singleton Token store or something....

Comment: I thought there might be a better way than that.  I could call my token manager in each class that deals with the third party api, if the token is not expired use it other wise call the auth API again.  For example I was thinking of having a class for each type of call, create user, get data.  I also have one call that will need to chain a second API call to a second third party API.  I have an API that get some pricing but the second third party api gives even more pricing and is merged into the first api call.  Sorry went on a bit of a tangent.

Comment: Well, unless *something* is holding onto the token between requests, then you wouldn't be able to check whether it's expired or not, unless it's being passed back to your API's clients.  in which case the requests would have the token attached...

Comment: Tokens generally have an expiration date within the token.  You only need to keep track of tokens if they can be refreshed.  If that's the case, the OP is better off using one of the already-implemented authentication providers rather than rolling his own.

Comment: I have 24 hours with a token and was saving a call to keep getting it.  We do have a quota so I was trying to save a call but I actually think the token call doesn't count against it.  I could just get a new token each time but in my old code I did manage the token with a tokenmanager and checked the date on it each time, if it was 23 hours old I would get a new token.  Token is used for every other call to the API.  I guess you can say I am building middleware api, I handle calls and redirect them to the third party API, handle the return and pass back to the client.

Comment: @Amy My reading of this is that this token is used by the back-end to talk to some other service, so if the back-end API doesn't have something to remember the token, it'll be gone once the initial request has been handled by the API - this token isn't going back to the original client...

Comment: @whreed I've edited my answer to expand on what I'd probably do - you DO need to be a bit careful with singletons (in particular, don't have a singleton which relies on services injected into it which may have a shorter lifetime!) but if their scope is very small as above this should be pretty manageable.

Comment: Quick question, and this is what I was looking for.  Is there ever a time where you do too many injections?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by too many injections?  Having too many services injected into one thing?  I've got plenty of things with multiple different services injected in, but don't think I've ever had more than maybe 8 or something.  lots of smaller services *generally* makes for easier testing and things having well defined roles, but as with anything you can take it too far.

Comment: @GPW That was what I was wondering.  You answered it.  Last question, I wanted to email you but can't do that through here.  I followed this example - https://github.com/donbavand/Giphy/blob/master/Giphy.Libs/Services/GiphyServices.cs - for DI and moved it over to .NET framework instead of Core.  This person uses Services that call a second class.  When I do DI I have to inject both the service and this interface IGetRandomGif.  Would I be better off just doing everything (HttpClient) and anything else I need inside the service only and not create this other class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182369/discussion-between-whreed-and-gpw).

Answer (score 0):

Unity as DI framework is not maintained anymore by Microsoft, is now in charge of the community, see here the link : [Unity Future](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/)

Now if you want to migrate the project to a new webapi, start looking for Aspnet core : [ASPNet Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#derive-class-from-controllerbase)

Now in terms of the token you can start looking for an integration with [Identity Server](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) it is an implementation of OAuth and OpenId and it has an integration with AspNet Core [AspNet Core Security Video](https://vimeo.com/294553362#t=1740s). You don't need to store the token at any time while you communicate with the Identity Provider(that can be Google, Facebook, etc), if you want to refresh the token, you can handle that yourself.
See an example below:

```
public interface IApplicationHttpClient
{
    Task<HttpClient> GetClient();
}

 public class ApplicationHttpClient : IApplicationHttpClient
    {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public ApplicationHttpClient(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task<HttpClient> GetClient()
    {
        string accessToken = string.Empty;

        // get the current HttpContext to access the tokens
        var currentContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        // get access token
        //accessToken = await currentContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);

        //should we renew access & refresh tokens?
        //get expires_at value
        var expires_at = await currentContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");

        //compare -make sure to use the exact date formats for comparison(UTC, in this case)
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expires_at) ||
            ((DateTime.Parse(expires_at).AddSeconds(-60)).ToUniversalTime() < DateTime.UtcNow))
        {
            accessToken = await RenewTokens();
        }
        else
        {
            //get access token
            accessToken = await currentContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken))
        {
            // set as Bearer token
            _httpClient.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
        }

        //api url
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44310/");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return _httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenewTokens()
    {
        //get the current HttpContext to access the tokens
        var currentContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        //get the metadata from the IDP
        var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient("https://localhost:44329/");
        var metaDataResponse = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();

        //create a new token client to get new tokens
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(metaDataResponse.TokenEndpoint, "mywebapp", "secret");

        //get the saved refresh token
        var currentRefreshToken = await currentContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken);

        //refresh the tokens
        var tokenResult = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(currentRefreshToken);

        if (!tokenResult.IsError)
        {
            var updatedTokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>();
            updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken
            {
                Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken,
                Value = tokenResult.IdentityToken
            });
            updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken
            {
                Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken,
                Value = tokenResult.AccessToken
            });
            updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken
            {
                Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken,
                Value = tokenResult.RefreshToken
            });

            var expiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenResult.ExpiresIn);
            updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken
            {
                Name = "expires-at",
                Value = expiresAt.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            });

            //get authenticate result, containing the current principal & properties
            var currentAuthenticateResult = await currentContext.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies");

            //store the updated tokens
            currentAuthenticateResult.Properties.StoreTokens(updatedTokens);

            //sign in
            await currentContext.SignInAsync("Cookies", currentAuthenticateResult.Principal,
                currentAuthenticateResult.Properties);

            //return the new access token
            return tokenResult.AccessToken;
        }

        throw new Exception("Problem encountered while refreshing tokens.", tokenResult.Exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have said that I can't go to Core.  This API will be living within Kentico.  Long story on that but lets just say it can't live outside of that.